# SharePoint 2013 - best practice to remove a design package - design manager

Tags: branding, design-manager

Best practice to remove design package in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best Practice is to not do it - as Microsoft doesn't support it.

"In SharePoint 2013 you cannot uninstall an imported design package, and you should never attempt to deactivate a design package through the solution gallery. If you do, page layout content types are removed and users may not be able to create subsites"

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862342.aspx

You may be able to work around this restriction if you export the page layout content types first, remove the custom ones, uninstall the package and then re-import the content types.  I've not tested this method however.